# Hibernate Configuration with only hibernate.properties file. Without any hibernate.cfg.xml

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, properties-file

Is it possible to use only `hibernate.properties` file to configure hibernate without any  `hibernate.cfg.xml` file?

I have defined the required properties in hibernate.properties file.

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.connection.driver_class=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dev
hibernate.connection.username=root
hibernate.connection.password=
hibernate.connection.pool_size=1
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.format_sql=true
hibernate.cache.provider_class=org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
```

Hibernate shows :

```
Loaded properties from resource hibernate.properties: {hibernate.connection.driver_class=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver, hibernate.cache.provider_class=org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider, hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect, hibernate.format_sql=true, hibernate.connection.username=root, hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update, hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dev, hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false, hibernate.show_sql=true, hibernate.connection.password=****, hibernate.connection.pool_size=1}
```

but it still asks for `cfg.xml` :

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Could not locate cfg.xml resource [hibernate.cfg.xml]
```

Comment: It is possible. see this [tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/introduction-to-hibernate-framework-architecture/).  place `hibernate.properties` in root of your applications CLASSPATH

Answer (score 1):

It is possible

```
SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().buildSessionFactory();
```